# Is codeblocks 10.05. compatible with QtWorkbench?

Tags: c++, qt, codeblocks

windows xp sp2 , codeblocks 10.05. , Qt 4.6

Does anyone know if codeblocks_10.05 is compatible with QtWorkbench-0.6.0_alpha.
I made everything written on http://code.google.com/p/qtworkbench but when I go to compile, codeblocks freeze.
I may have made a mistake somewhere in the setup, I do not know.

The main question: Is it even CB 10:05 compatible with qtworkbench 0.6.0 alpha.

Please give us your experiences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FROM CREATOR OF QtWorkBench:

Comment 12  by y.pagles, Jun 11, 2009

I don't think that it's going to work with any different revision than the 8.02 one.

So , the answer is 99%  NO !!!